# Вопрос по сборщику мусора

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Есть объявление глобальной переменной `Client t`.

В одном из методов создал `(t = new Client("name1"));`.

Забросил этот объект в `ArrayList`.

Затем снова создал новый объект на ту же ссылку  `(t = new Client(name2));`.

Забросил и этот объект в `ArrayList`.

Удалит ли "сборщик мусора" предыдущий объект?

Смогу ли я обращаться к предыдущему объекту?

Comment: 1. Сборщик все удалит корректно - кому он вообще был бы нужен, не умей он делать подобные вещи

2. А что вам мешает это проверить самому? (хотя ответ довольно очевиден)

Comment: > удалит ли "сборщик мусора" предыдущий объект?

Объект, лежащий в списке, не будет удален, пока существует ссылка на этот список.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сборщик мусора не будет удалять объект, пока на него есть хоть одна ссылка. Исключением являются случаи обособленных циклических ссылок: если A ссылается на B, B ссылается на A, при этом ни на A, ни на B никто больше не ссылается, то оба объекта будут удалены. Если вы положили объект в список, то внутри списка на него создана ссылка. Пока вы не потеряете ссылку на список, сборщик мусора не будет удалять объекты, хранящиеся в списке.

```
Client t = new Client("name1");
List<Client> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(t);                    // Сейчас на Client("name1") 2 ссылки - t и внутри l
t = new Client("name2");     // А сейчас только одна - внутри l
l = null;                    // Пропала последняя ссылка на l, поэтому GC его удалит
// А после удаления l никто не будет ссылаться на Client("name1"), и его тоже удалят
```

Важно помнить, что сборщик мусора отрабатывает не сразу, а только при необходимости (например, если заканчивается память). Поэтому объект может провисеть в памяти неопределённое время после исчезновения всех ссылок на него. Также стоит помнить, что нет надёжного способа вручную запустить сборщик мусора. Метод `System.gc()` является лишь "советом" запустить сборку, и JVM может его проигнорировать, если считает, что в данный момент сборка не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли :)