# Что делает сборщик мусора, когда мы пишем new Object(), а не Object obj = new Object()?

Tags: java, ссылки, сборщик-мусора

Сборщик мусора видит что сcылок на только созданный объект нет и удаляет?

---

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

---

```
new Object();
```

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Сборщик мусора удаляет те объекты, на которые нет ссылок - которые уже никак не могут быть использованы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вопрос по сборщику мусора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/395462/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)